# C# conditional regex replace and phone formatting

Tags: c#, regex, formatting

Is there any way to do a Regex Replace conditionally?  Here's an example.

Say you have a number that you know corresponds to a phone, with no formatting:

```
5553331234
```

Formatted, it would be

```
(555)333-1234
```

However, we don't have the number formatted and want to apply formatting.  You can do an easy regex match and capture each of the 3 groups with something along the following:

```
(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})
```

From there, you can do a simple regex replace

```
($2)$3-$4
```

However, what if you *might* have an extension? Maybe you have more than the 10 standard phone digits:

```
555333123456789
```

Where 56789 would be an extension.  In that case, I could match it with

```
(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d*)
```

If I want to format it, but only include the X for extension *if* it exists, can I do that?  For instance, I could make my replace format:

```
($2)$3-$4x$5
```

However, if I did that, the x would show up even when there is no extension.  Is there a way purely using the regex to make that x show up conditionally?  Essentially it would be "if $5" exists or "if $5.Length() > 0".

As a workaround, I could include a named group in that regex match where (\d*) above becomes

```
(?<Conditional>\d*)
```

In the code, I could then assert the length of the group named "Conditional".  However, I'd like to have a purely regex solution that does not require anything custom like that.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Substitutions in Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx) - there's no replacement pattern that would allow you to write a conditional. Other libraries, like boost::regex [do provide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html) such facilities, but you don't get that in .NET.

What you *do* get though is the ability to use a callback to supply the replacement. Just use a lambda:

```
Regex.Replace(
    "555333123456789",
    @"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d+)?",
    m => $"({m.Groups[1].Value}){m.Groups[2].Value}-{m.Groups[3].Value}{(m.Groups[4].Success ? $"x{m.Groups[4].Value}" : "")}"
)
```

Yes, I know that's not a *pure regex* solution, but it does its job. Remember that *substitution* is *not really* a regex operation, it's rather a post-matching step which does involve the result of a match but does *not* involve the regex engine itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the overload of `Regex.Replace` that takes a `MatchEvaluator` which will allow you to do conditional logic based on the matched groups.

```
var phone = "5553331234";
Regex phoneRegex = new Regex(@"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d*)");
var formatted = phoneRegex.Replace(
    phone, 
    m => string.Format(
        "({0}){1}-{2}{3}{4}", 
        m.Groups[1].Value, 
        m.Groups[2].Value, 
        m.Groups[3].Value, 
        m.Groups[4].Value.Length > 0 ? "x" : string.Empty, 
        m.Groups[4].Value));
Console.WriteLine(formatted);
```